# fixed avfoundation variables, different display brightness

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have used avfoundation to fix the ISO/whitebalance/exposure of iPad values to fixed values in an AR App. I put the iPad on a tripod. If I switch the lighting in the space from A to B and back to A, the iPad display brightness and color are not stable.

Any solution to this?

I tried to fix all the avfoundation variables using the following codes, but still the display will change.

```
    case .wbset2:
        device2?.unlockForConfiguration()
        do {
            if ((try device2?.lockForConfiguration()) != nil) {

                var g = (device2?.deviceWhiteBalanceGains)!
                g.redGain = 1.685
                g.greenGain = 1
                g.blueGain = 2.367

                device2?.setWhiteBalanceModeLocked(with: g, completionHandler: nil)
                var dur: CMTime = device2!.exposureDuration
                dur = CMTimeMake(value: 1964000, timescale: 1000000000)

                device2?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoHDREnabled = false

                device2?.setExposureModeCustom(duration: dur, iso: 121.9, completionHandler: nil)

                try device2?.lockForConfiguration()

                var wbg2 = device2?.deviceWhiteBalanceGains
                lab_ij.text = "wb: \(wbg2)"
                lab_exp.text = "duration: \(device2?.exposureDuration),iso:\(device2?.iso)"
            }
        } catch{
        }
```

Comment: Could you share some code that you have tried ?

Comment: @Fourat, i revised the post and posted my codes.